# Moving mails from SBS 2008 to SBS 2011

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs-2011, mailbox, migration

we are going to upgrade server from SBS 2008 to a new hardware server with SBS 2011.

Due to non-experience in Server Migration (eg, answer file), we have decided to choose Clean Install. We have 12 users so that's not too bad.

The most challenge problem is to move over all the emails for each user, some user have 5GB inbox. The one method I know is to login to each user account and export the emails to PST file using Outlook 2007. Then connect to new SBS 2011 and import the PST into new inbox.

Do we have any other better/quicker ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider "user1825647" answer unhelpful as I'm currently doing several SBS 2003 to SBS 2011 migrations too.

[exmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2743)

Will be the tool I'll be using - from my research it creates PST's from the server as opposed to using the client's Outlook (less leg work which is never a bad thing :D ).

Then using the "Import-Mailbox" cmdlet in the Exchange 2010 Shell to import the PST's for the users. I'll more than likely be creating a powershell script to automate the import from PST's to mailboxes - if you want a copy let me know!

useful link - 
[Tutorial Export/Import Mailboxes Exchange 2010](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exporting-importing-mailboxes-exchange-server-2010.html)

Comment: Good idea. wish see your answer earlier. I have done it, with Outlook (a lot of leg working).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have adequate permission for the migration.

First make the new users and the respective mailboxes in the new environment using exchange tool. Then you can migrate the mailboxes to respective users.

Make sure that the new mailboxes created are based for the new exchange server. You are just making a replica of all these mailboxes of the old exchange server in the new exchange server. Also make sure that the windows server configuration supports your migration and also take care that whether you are doing inter forest or cross forest migration. There are a lot of third party utility tools that are available for doing this migration from SBS 2008 to SBS 2011.